# How to fix receiving unregistered task error - Celery

Tags: python, linux, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to establish a periodic task using Celery (4.2.0) and RabbitMQ (3.7.14) running with Python 3.7.2 on an Azure VM using Ubuntu 16.04. I am able to start the beat and worker and see the message get kicked off from beat to the worker but at this point I'm met with an error like so

```sh
[2019-03-29 21:35:00,081: ERROR/MainProcess] Received 
unregistered task of type 'facebook-call.facebook_api'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?
```

My code is as follows:

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery('facebook-call', broker='amqp://localhost//')

@app.task
def facebook_api():
    {function here}

app.conf.beat.schedule = {
    'task': 'facebook-call.facebook_api',
    'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute =0, day='0-6'),
}
```

I am starting the beat and worker processes by using the name of the python file which contains all of the code

```py
celery -A FacebookAPICall beat --loglevel=info
```

```py
celery -A FacebookAPICall worker --loglevel=info
```

Again, the beat process starts and I can see the message being successfully passed to the worker but cannot figure out how to "register" the task so that it is processed by the worker.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by renaming the app from `facebook-call` to coincide with the name of the file `FacebookAPICall`

Before:
`app = Celery('facebook-call', broker='amqp://localhost//'`

After:
`app = Celery('FacebookAPICall', broker='amqp://localhost//'`

From reading the Celery documentation, I don't totally understand why the name of the app must also be the name of the `.py` file but that seems to do the trick.